# PHP/SQL - querying relational DB for IDs but being able to query those IDs in seperate DB using ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql

I have an ecommerce site where I have some products that can be in multiple categories.

I therefore have a products table, a categories table, and a product_categories table.

So what I do is query the product_categories table for the category ID of the category I want and get an array of product IDs like so:

```
$product_ids = [];
$params = [$category_id];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product_categories WHERE category_id=?";
$stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $product_id = $row['product_id'];
    array_push($product_ids,$product_id);
}
```

I then have a `show_products` function which takes the array and spits out all of the products. However, this function has a foreach statement like so:

```
foreach($ids as $id){
    $params = [$id];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = DB::run($sql,$params);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        //show products
    }
}
```

This is fine and works but I want to be able to determine the order of which the products are displayed, so in my products table I have an 'order_by' column and would like to do something like `SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=? ORDER BY order_by ASC`.

Obviously the way I'm set up at the moment means that it is doing the query for 1 id at a time so it can't order them in this way.

I was thinking to get around this I would need to query myproducts like I've done above but instead of showing the products at this stage I would get the order_by column and create another array and sort them by this order nand then actually use that array to query again and show the products.

Is there a better way of doing this?

**Note: I would like to keep my `show_products` function seperate for use in other parts of my site as it is fairly complicated (gets 'as low as' price and stock levels etc). So I want to be able to just pass an array of IDs to this function.

Comment: You really need to research the sql JOIN Syntax so you can get all this as one query.

Comment: Hi. Hmm, your question seems to be vague while you don't tell exactly what you want to do. Minimize your code? Adjust performance? Improve querying to DB? Without exact understanding it's hard to say what type of advice we can give. If you have many questions - let's start asking one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my final SQL query.

```
SELECT product_categories.product_id
FROM product_categories INNER JOIN products ON product_categories.product_id=products.id
WHERE product_categories.category_id=?
ORDER BY products.order_by ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to move some logic to the SQL query from PHP code.
I think that for doing this you should modify your `show_products` function too, look at [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) Syntax and [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function syntax.

Here is an example of what you can do with a simple JOIN and a GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function (assuming to have products.name and categories.description columns):

```
    SELECT P.ID, P.name, GROUP_CONCAT(C.description) 
    FROM products P
    INNER JOIN product_categories PC ON P.category_id = PC.id
    INNER JOIN categories C ON PC.category_id = C.id
    GROUP BY P.ID, P.name
```